# What does openGL do with empty/uninitialized data sent to it?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I'm wondering what happens to data that is sent without any information, ex:

```
struct Vertex
{
    glm::vec3 Positions, UVs, Normals;
};

std::vector<Vertex> vertices;
// We fill vertices with a bunch of Vertex' that only have Positions and UVs filled in.
// Normals aren't iniatalized so im assuming they're a glm::vec3(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f) by default
```

Later in the code while creating the buffers we send the data, we allocate the buffers to have a size of `sizeof(Vertex) * vertices[0]`.

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), reinterpret_cast<GLvoid*>(offsetof(Vertex, Positions)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), reinterpret_cast<GLvoid*>(offsetof(Vertex, UVs)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), reinterpret_cast<GLvoid*>(offsetof(Vertex, Normals)));
```

What does the shader do with the `Vertex::Normal` data in each of the two instances in shaders:

1.)

```
#version 450 core
layout(location = 0) in vec3 Pos;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 UVs;
layout(location = 2) in vec3 Norms;
void main()
{
    // We only use Pos and UVs, Norms is never referenced.
}
```

2.)

```
#version 450 core
layout(location = 0) in vec3 Pos;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 UVs;
void main(){...}
```

1.)
For one I expect the shader to store the uninitialized vec3 of Norms since we give it a location to retrieve the data. But I've also heard that shaders discard any data that isn't used.

2.) 
I expect the vec3 of Norms to be discarded as it doesn't have a location in the shader even though i still send the data through with the `glVertexAttribArray(...)`

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever happens is not *observable* behavior. That is, there's nothing that you can do to test what happens. Even performance tests are not conclusive as to what happens.

The OpenGL specification says that it's legal to pass attributes that are never used by the VS (either because you never use the variable that catches them or no variable catches them). But whether some internal register gets loaded with a value or not simply is not something that we can know.

If the real question you're asking is, "is it worth it to change my VAO if some shader I want to use with it doesn't catch one of the value," the answer will generally be "no". Especially with your interleaved vertex data, since the GPU will still be fetching all of that data into the pre-T&L cache.

VAO vertex format changes are non-trivially expensive. Shader changes aren't cheap either, but you don't want to do both. On some hardware, doing both won't actually be any worse than doing one or other other, but on some hardware it will be worse.